# Android ClassNotFoundException on working project (pre eclipse crash)

Tags: android, eclipse

I have an Android project that built and ran perfectly before Eclipse crashed and corrupted the workspace.

Eclipse would not start until I deleted(moved) the `.metadata` folder from the workspace folder.

Now, the project will build fine and install on my device but when it starts I get the following error on LogCat:

Any idea on how I could fix?

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.conor.app/com.conor.app.StartActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.conor.app.StartActivity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.conor.app.StartActivity
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so I solved the problem. It seemed that deleting the .metadata folder would let Eclipse start again but the project seemed a bit messed up.

My solution is as follows:

- Delete `.metadata` folder from workspace
- Move all projects out of workspace to some other place (temporary location)
- Start up eclipse and select your workspace. This will rebuild the `.metadata` folder
- From Eclipse import all your projects that are contained in the temporary location

Hope it helps if you've had this problem

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a lib folder in your project. If you have a lib folder rename it to libs.
With latest ADT lib folders renamed to libs and causes that error. 
I had same problem last month and after I googled a bit I solved it with renaming lib folder.

Comment: I've had issues with "lib" before so all my folders are "libs" now, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please assure that your AndroidManifest is corrent and not corrupted.

Have you defined com.conor.app.StartActivity Activity in your manifest?

Comment: Yes, I have everything declared in the AndroidManifest.

Comment: That's pretty strange because that's the common error when you have not defined your class in your manifest. I think that something is went really wrong in Eclipse building process for your app. Please try to make a clean/build for all your workspace projects